# Piping output of bash function

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I'm trying to connect the inputs/outputs of two bash functions with a
pipe. Here is a complete program which illustrates my issue:

```
function print_info {
    files=$(ls);
    echo $files;
}
touch "file.pattern"
print_info | grep "pattern"
rm -f file.pattern
```

But this simply outputs a list of all files, not those that match
"pattern". Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that in

```
echo $files;
```

the variable `$files` is subject to shell expansion (i.e., it is expanded into individual arguments to `echo`), and the resulting tokens are printed by `echo` delimited by spaces. This means that the output of it is a single line, and `grep` handles it accordingly.

The least invasive fix is to use

```
echo "$files";
```

Comment: I just tried this fix, and it didn't seem to help. The output still prints all files, not those that match the pattern.

Comment: Are you doing something else with the variable `$files` in the function? With just those two mentioned lines, this would have to be it.

Comment: I edited my question to include a complete test case of how it's not working. It doesn't involve any of the other code in the function it seems.

Comment: Works for me. What shell are you using?

Comment: Whoops! I, uh, forgot to save my changes :-). Thanks for the help. I'm going to restore the question to the original so that the problem is clear for readers.

Comment: I would have been very surprised to find a shell that behaves differently here :P By the way, is there a reason you don't just use `ls *pattern*` (or just `*pattern*`, depending on context) or so? Or `find -regex`, if globs are not good enough. `ls | grep` is a little odd because `ls`'s formatting is not standardized terribly strictly.

Comment: More generally, I have a script where I'm trying to connect functions with pipes. This was the just the simplest way I could reduce the problem I was seeing down to something easily testable.

Comment: Oh, I see. Carry on, then.

Answer (score 0):

Dont parse the output of ls command. You could do the same using find command like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep "pattern" {} \;
```

if you are getting file names from a function then do it like:

```
grep "pattern" $(print_info)
```

Comment: Well, this example of `ls | grep` was just to illustrate my problem. More generally, I don't understand why piping the output of my `print_info` function does not seem to work.